# Launch an Eclipse Run Configuration from ANT

Tags: eclipse, ant, eclipse-orion

I am using Orion server for my Java-based web application.  I have a run configuration that launches Orion with the correct classpaths and all necessary configuration. I also have several ANT scripts for copying files to the build path.  I want to create an ANT script that shuts down Orion, copies necessary files, and restarts Orion.  I can shutdown and copy in ANT, but I can't figure out how to launch a run configuration. I prefer to reference the launch configuration as opposed to specifying all of the configurations in the ANT script as well.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ant4Eclipse](http://www.ant4eclipse.org/) is an Eclipse plugin and looks like it can do what you are asking. I have never used it myself so can't guarantee but reading their [documentation](http://www.ant4eclipse.org/userguide-coreconcepts) they say you can create an [Executor](http://www.ant4eclipse.org/userguide-executors) task that works on your launch configuration artifact. You will then reference this task in your build file.

Answer (score 4):

With [eclipse remote control](http://github.com/marook/eclipse-remote-control) you can launch eclipse run configurations in eclipse from a simple java client application.