# Execute a function before debug in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, configuration, launch

Does anyone know if it's possible in Eclipse, to execute a script/function/anything right before launching my app in debug?  There only seems to be a few options - after clean, during a clean, during manual builds, during auto-builds

I want to execute an external tool (rsync) so I can make sure my assets are up to date before running.

Cheers,

Shane

Answer (score 1):

[Eclipse CDT](http://eclipse.org/cdt/) provides special launch configuration type (Launch Group), which you can use to group several launch configurations (included External Tools) to be executed either sequentially, parallel or mixed. The drawback is that you need to have CDT installed in your Eclipse.

Update: There is similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4053265/eclipse-running-multiple-launch-configurations-at-once), which deals with launching multiple launch configurations.

Comment: Im checking out escripts, which I found from your link.  Fingers crossed!

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47302032/394431) CDT is no longer needed for Launch Group configurations.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the "Launch Group" feature onto an existing, not necessarily CDT, eclipse install, you can install just the plugin called "C/C++ Remote Launch". (org.eclipse.cdt.launch.remote) - it is not C/C++ specific.