# What installable component provides 'launch groups' in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

My installation of Indigo has 'Launch Group' in the debug configuration window. My colleague's does not. What do I have installed that he does not?

To see them, I click on the arrow next to the bug icon, I select 'Debug Configurations...', and I see a green arrow labelled 'Launch Group' in the list of top-level items on the left.

See http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fcdt_u_run_dbg_launch_group.htm

Comment: Please post a screenshot so it's clearer where the launch groups appear (is it a tab, a configuration type, something else?)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4053265/eclipse-running-multiple-launch-configurations-at-once ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I understand now. Based on [this page](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/eclipse_documentation/eclipse_c_c++_guide/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/concepts/eclipse_c_c++_guide_cdt_c_whatsnew.htm#debugAndLaunch), it looks like it's contributed by the CDT feature set (as of version 6.0). Check that your colleague has CDT installed.

Answer (score 40):

While E-Riz's answer is correct, if you just want to add the "Launch Group" feature onto an existing eclipse install, you can install just the extension called "C/C++ Remote Launch". (org.eclipse.cdt.launch.remote)

Note: this extension is entirely language independent, can be added to any type of eclipse install. The "C/C++" part is probably just because it originated from CDT.

(CDT is a collection of eclipse extensions: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers/lunar)

Comment: E. g.: Help -> Install new software -> Neon - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon -> Launch Tools -> C/C++ Remote Launch

Comment: worked for me!. I had multiple java projects and with "C/C++ Remote Launch" I was able to launch them at one go.

Comment: Since Eclipse Oxygen (4.7) the "Launch Group" is part of the debug platform and available without having CDT or "C/C+ Remote Launch" installed.