# Can a "run configuration" ensure another app is running?

Tags: eclipse, mule

When working with Mule ESB, we need to have (in our case) ActiveMQ running (in a terminal) or it won't work. That's fine, but I sometimes forget to start ActiveMQ, which caused me to wonder...

Can I somehow explain to my "Run configuration" that it should start an external program in conjunction with starting the run|debug session? And if so, can it be configured to only start it if it's *not already* running?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether you can run the external application using your project run configurations. But from mule studio you can start the external application using Run--> External tools. Refer the below kink for details

http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-exttools-running.htm

Comment: Thank you very much, but I already know this. The goal is _automation_, not do-everything-from-within-Eclipse. :)

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse CDT contains a useful type of launch configuration called a Launch Group. With a launch group you can set up different launches to run and what order. You can optionally add delays between launches (to allow for your service to start) or wait for a set up launch to terminate before running the next one.

To install the launch groups you can add "C/C++ Development Tools" to your installation.

Once installed, you should have a new launch type called a launch group.

Here is an example of one that may address your first question:

[Launch Group Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEEbo.png)

As my example shows, you don't need to have any CDT launches to be able to use Launch Groups.

As for your second part. This is in active development. Eclipse EASE is adding full scriptability to Eclipse and as it turns out I have just written a post about adding launching capabilities to the scripting. You can follow that work on bugzilla: [Bug 478397](https://bugs.eclipse.org/478397)

Comment: I also wrote a blog post about the new launch functionality http://kichwacoders.com/2015/10/04/launching-with-ease/ but basically you should be able to write a small bit of javascript (or your favourite supported scripting language) and test if your ActiveMQ is running and spawn it if not.

Comment: This sounds like it might be _exactly_ what I'm after, even including killing the external program when the run|debug session ends. Very nice!

Comment: I've been looking at the EASE components and what to install. It looks like your "System/Launch" is not available yet. I'll keep an eye on it though!

Comment: System/Launch is a WIP, feel free to add yourself to the CC list on https://bugs.eclipse.org/478397 and you should be notified when it is in in EASE. Knowing that at least one other person is interested helps the motivation too :-)