# How to run multiple mains on eclipse without starting each one individually one by one

Tags: eclipse

I'm working on a distributed system with a minimum of 6 servers and 3 clients (I cannot test it properly if I use less).

You probably can guess that it's a pain to start 9 processes individually (I need to have each one in a different console)

Is there a way to make a shortcut inside eclipse to start all those executions?

Comment: Possibly not the best option, but you could write a short launcher class that launches your processes with `Runtime.exec()` from java (I assumed you are using java).

Comment: Yeah, I think this feature is not supported by default in Eclipse. However, you can easily create workaround like @assylias recommended (with different Threads, of course), or try writing a simple batch/bash script that starts the proper processes individually (don't forget the `&` to make it background process), use an Ant script for that (don't forget the `fork="true"` flag), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the [CDT launch groups feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11369639/44089) (only that, not the whole CDT). That gives you the ability to create a batch like launch group consisting of other launch configurations.

Comment: If I go here: "CDT Indigo - download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/indigo"; and I search for launch. I only find "remote launch". Where can I find usage instructions for it?

Comment: Thats exactly what you need to install. After having installed it, open your run configurations dialog in Eclipse and find a new entry "launch groups". It looks like this: http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/images/60/Run_debug_launch_group.png

Comment: Ok, thank you. That was really helpful. I wasn't understanding properly the first time, now I got it right.