# Launch Groups in Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-luna

I'm trying to add "Launch Groups" as an option within my Run/Debug Configurations in Eclipse Luna, but it just won't show up.

From the [CDT Update Site](http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/8.6) I have installed both the "C/C++ Development Tools" as per [this answer for running multiple launch configurations at once](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11905444/4965550) as well as the "C/C++ Remote Launch" package as per [this answer for what installable component provides 'launch groups' in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11369639/534195), but Eclise still doesn't give me the option to add new "Launch Groups".

Answer (score 1):

Not a perfect solution by any means, but I was able to get the "Launch Groups" functionality working within Eclipse Luna by installing the following packages from the [Kepler CDT Update Site](http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/kepler).

- "C/C++ Development Tools"
- "C/C++ Remote Launch"