# eclipse - compile multiple project in special order

Tags: eclipse, compilation

short question, is there a way to build two java projects in eclipse in a special order?
the first project is a server, the second a gui. 
so, at first the server should be compiled/run than the gui.
couldn´t find a way in eclipse.
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it. 
launch groups are the solution...

Answer (score 1):

Specify server project in gui's project Properties/Java Build Path.
When you attempt to build gui it will check and re-build server if needed.

Comment: but i need the server to be startet/executed(before running the gui), if i debug/run the gui... 
i need this just for debug purposes

Comment: You may need to create an ant script to do that.
Or try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4053265/eclipse-running-multiple-launch-configurations-at-once