# Can I add a button in eclipse which performs custom a list of Actions in order?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

This may not be possible but I'm looking for a way to add a button (or option in right click menu of project) that allows me to perform what would normally be multiple separate actions , specifically I would like an option that would:

1. perform a Maven clean on the current project
2. clean the project in eclipse
3. clean the server and rebuild (normally or Debug)

I have tried to Google this but I couldn't find anything that might help (I may not of phrased it correctly though as I am not sure what to search for)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the actions you listed can be done by separate builders. So you can create a launch config to run the Maven clean action, another launch config to run the Eclipse clean command and so on.

When you have all of those launch configs available, install the CDT launch group feature to run them together with one click: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11905444/44089

Answer (score 0):

There have been a number of scripting attempts with eclipse, but not many of them are successful.  You can always write your own command and handler, and from there you can execute any number of commands that you can specify:

```
public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
    IWorkbenchWindow window = HandlerUtil
            .getActiveWorkbenchWindowChecked(event);
    IHandlerService handlerService = (IHandlerService) window
            .getService(IHandlerService.class);
    try {
        handlerService.executeCommand(
                IWorkbenchCommandConstants.HELP_ABOUT, null);
        handlerService.executeCommand(
                IWorkbenchCommandConstants.FILE_REFRESH, null);
    } catch (NotDefinedException | NotEnabledException
            | NotHandledException e) {
        throw new ExecutionException("Failed", e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then you just need to track down command IDs that correspond to what you want to do. `ALT+SHIFT+F2` and then selecting a menu item can provide the command ID (or action definition ID, which is the same thing).