# Running multiple run configurations

Tags: eclipse

I have two run configurations and I would like to run the first, then, after that is done, run the second. Can I do that in Eclipse in a single step? And, if so, can I also assign this to a keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [similar Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4053265/eclipse-running-multiple-launch-configurations-at-once), though that one is slightly different I think you can use the same solution. It looks like, according to [the Eclipse Help page about Launch Groups](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/reference/cdt_u_run_dbg_launch_group.htm), that you can define a sequence of launches in a group. The drawback is that you must install CDT to get this feature, but it's not only for C/C++ applications.