# how eclipse runner plugin run several debug configuration at once

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

how eclipse runner plugin run several java debug configuration at once?

or we the plugin dosent support this work?

I know CDT plugin can do this,but i want to know if runner plugin can do this for me?

Comment: anymore , I want to stop the task at once , too!  Any way ?

Comment: Did you mean  *How can I define more than one debug configurations in the Runner plugin for Eclipse and choose which one to use each time I debug?*

Comment: No Sir!!   I mean run all of them  at once!!

Comment: Because  I must start all of the java application service   before  debuging a web  project！

Comment: possible duplicate of [eclipse: running multiple launch configurations at once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4053265/eclipse-running-multiple-launch-configurations-at-once)