# Maven: run a build for multiple profiles in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-profiles

Let's suppose we have a Maven project in Eclipse.
The pom.xml has two profiles.

The question is: how can I run maven in Eclipse in order to execute every goals for each profile?

I tried to:

- setting active maven profiles in Properties/Maven -> didn't work
- run maven with: clean install -Pprofile1 -Pprofile2 -> didn't work
- run maven with: clean install -P profile1,profile2 -> didn't work
- run maven setting "Profiles" under "Goals" ( profile1,profile2) -> didn't work

I want that maven will run for both profiles, executing all tasks in the pom.xml

Thanks.

Comment: What is the purpose of those profiles? What are the differences?

Comment: The purpose is: run a build with both profiles. The build itself makes different things on each profile. I simply want to run the build one single time with both profiles and combine the result of the build of profile1 with the build of the profile2

Comment: sorry but your answer you have written does not answer my question. What is being done for the different profiles? Why are those profiles needed?

Comment: That's not relevant what the build has to do. I simply want to know how can I have in the target folder the result of the build with profile1 with the build of the profile2. Each build produces a "profile1" or "profile2" folder in target. So I want to produce both in the same time.

Comment: What do you exactly get, if you specify all profiles in the Maven run configuration? As a workaround, the Maven run configurations for the different profiles can be combined in a _Launch Group_: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47302032/6505250

Comment: If I specify all the profiles, only one is built. The _Launch Group_ function looks interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you do it
[Eclipse Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j56Bx.png)

Comment: Giving multiple profiles seperated by a space (which i think you propose) does not work for me. Only the last profile is used.