# Eclipse/Android Studio/WebStorm/IntelliJ run a continuous process in parallel

Tags: eclipse, android-studio, intellij-idea, webstorm

I have a process that is building some modules each time I make changes to my code. The process is continuous unless I close it and I want to run it each time I launch my app. I can see a `before launch` section in my `Run/Debug Configurations` settings of my IDE but, If I add my process there, the main process is never spawned since the IDE is probably waiting for the first one to finish.

Any idea how to make these two run in parallel?

Comment: It's called [Launch groups in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4054155/2834978) but it's just a multi-launch one after the other, I don think they run in parallel. Probably the same for IntelliJ.

Comment: @LMC In parallel or one after the other (with or without a delay) can be chosen: https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/debug_launch_groups.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Compound run/debug configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2021.2/run-debug-configuration.html#compound-configs).

Comment: Unfortunately it makes the "debug" icon/command go away but this is the right answer for this question.

Comment: You can also try https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7248-multirun.